# How to keep line breaks in CKEditor WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, ckeditor

I have an HTML code as follows

```
<div class="editable" ...>
  <div class="code">
    This is an example.
    This is a new line
  </div>
</div>
```

In CSS, code has "word-wrap: pre" attribute, such that the text in the inner DIV will show two lines. I use CKEditor with DIV replacement method to edit it. However, it becomes

```
  <div class="code">
    This is an example.This is a new line
  </div>
```

The text inside the HTML tag will become one line long, beginning and trailing spaces and new line are stripped. So in CKEditor, although I have specified the config.contentsCss, it still shows one line because CKEditor has merge those two lines into one (I checked this in Chrome "Inspect Element" in CKEditor's iframe editor). Therefore, I see the source code or saved HTML, two lines format is not preserved because they are only one line.

I've googled and tried the CKEditor HTML writer or addRules to restrict the indent format and new line in begin/close tags, however, those seems work on HTML tags, not the document text. Is there any other methods to preserve line breaks of text?

Comment: You need the code formatted inside CKEditor?

Comment: NO, I don't want the code formatted, such that it keeps all whitespace s and line breaks before/after CKeditor.

Comment: Then you'll have to deal with line breaks (\n) and <br>'s

Comment: I don't have to deal with line breaks manually. Actually, if CKeditor think it can strip all begin and tail white-spaces `(^[ \n\r\t]*|[ \n\r\t]*$)`, it means those does not affect the layout of line breaks viewed in the browser. But why this affect the result as I described in the problem because I have a CSS style of using `word-wrap: pre`, and CKeditor does not know that. It delete those white-spaces and make the viewing strange.
And I find the solution, however, there is no config option to control that. It is acceptable with a very small hack.

Comment: @jclin could you share the solution by answering your own question?

Comment: Argh, I've done it before, but I can't look up the code until monday. (In my case, it was a custom tag, I will check if that makes any difference.)

Answer (score 7):

I found it.

```
// preserve newlines in source
config.protectedSource.push( /\n/g );
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource

Comment: Initially I though this is good and simple solution, but it turns out it might wrap any new line found in things like custom tags attributes with  something like &lt;!--{cke_protected}%A--&gt;. This is not good in attribute values, so beware.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in CKEditor5 ? I can't find any trace of the `protectedSource()` method in the codex: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/index.html . Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<pre>` HTML tag.  Like this:

```html
<div class="editable" ...>
  <div class="code"><pre>
    This is an example in a "pre".
    This is a new line
  </pre></div>
</div>

<div class="editable" ...>
      <div class="code">
        This is an example NOT in a "pre".
        Therefore this is NOT a new line
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or you can put a `<br/>` tag in between your lines.  Its the ssame as hitting enter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('paste', 'textarea', function (e) {
    $(e.target).keyup(function (e) {
        var inputText = $(e.target).val();
        $(e.target).val(inputText.replace(/\n/g, '<br />'))
                .unbind('keyup');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's only on `paste` events. What if someone needs to type out multiple lines in the source mode and keep the line breaks?

Comment: since CKEditor builds/keeps a tree model of HTML, it's probably not possible to keep that. anyway, they allow custom display: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/htmlformatting.html

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, it was an extra tag, `univis`, that I needed to give similar semantics (i.e., leave indentation and inebreaks alone), and what we ended up doing was:

```
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$block.univis=1;
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$cdata.univis=1;
    CKEDITOR.dtd.univis=CKEDITOR.dtd.script;
```

But that looks like it might or might not be extensible to classes.

Comment: What do those lines do when you add them to CKEditor? What do you mean that in your case "it" was an extra tag? To what does "it" refer when you say "it was an extra tag to give similar semantics"? Instead of the word "semantics" do you mean "functionality" - i.e. If your sentence was rewritten - is this the meaning: "In my case, to get the function desired (i.e. leave line breaks alone), we ended up doing this:"

Comment: We tried this and it seems to have no effect on line-breaks as we switch back and forth between viewing the source and viewing the rendered HTML in CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

I got some Craft sites running and I don't want to paste the config file everywhere. For everyone else still having the problem: Just use redactor. Install and replace the field type. Correct everything once and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use javascript replace function

```
.replace( /\n/g, '</p><p>' )
```